# Getting 2 variables from 1 ajax call in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

I was wondering how you can get 2 variables to update a div tag using an ajax call instead of just 1. My current .js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select").change(function() {
        var selected_product_id;
        selected_product_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "/products/" + selected_product_id,
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
          $("#description").empty().append(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

show.html.erb where i get the data:

```
    <%= @product.item %>
```

I would like something like this

```
        $.ajax({
          url: "/products/" + selected_product_id,
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data) {
          $("#description").empty().append(data[1]);
          $("#price").empty().append(data[2]);
          }
        });
```

with

```
        <%= @product.item %>
        <%= @product.price %>
```

where my description div gets updated with @product.item and my price div gets updated with @product.price. How could I achieve this?

**EDIT**

updated .js file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select").change(function() {
        var selected_product_id;
        selected_product_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "/products/" + selected_product_id,
          type: "json",
          success: function(data) {
          $("#description").empty().append(product.item);
          $("#price").empty().append(product.price)
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

show.html.erb:

```
    <%= @product.item %>
    <%= @product.price %>
```

controller:

```
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @product.to_json }
    end

    def index
    end

    def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    end
```

I'm pretty sure that controller isn't correct. I placed @product before respond_to and it didn't work so I just put respond_to without really knowing where it goes. Sorry for being such a noob. Thanks for all your help.

**FINAL EDIT:**

working javascript file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select").change(function() {
        var selected_product_id;
        selected_product_id = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("/products/"+selected_product_id,function(data){
      $("#description").empty().append(data.item);
      $("#price").empty().append(data.price);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: have you considered using a `form_for` or `form_tag`?

Comment: @derek_duncan i have my select tag and some text input fields in a form_for tag. How could I use that to populate the divs dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, This remembers me a piece of code I wrote for you a week ago!

You can use JSON to render your Product:

```
#controller

def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @product.to_json }
  end
end
```

And handle the response from the server like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/products/" + selected_product_id,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        var product = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#description").empty().append(product.item);
        $("#price").empty().append(product.price);
      }
    });
```

**Edit #1:** I found this method: `jQuery.getJSON` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: ok thank you. What should i put in my show.html.erb file? I tried returning an array like @user1737909 suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: You can leave the show.html.erb as it already is. This file will be rendered if you make a request to `/products/[:id]` with HTML format.

Comment: goll darnit it still doesn't work. sorry for being such a noob. i have edited my question with the updated files.

Comment: alright when i navigate to products/1.json it outputs this: {"created_at":null,"group":"dairy","id":1,"item":"milk","price":"3.0","updated_at":null}. it seems like that is correct so i would think appending product.item product.price would work but it isn't. do you think there is something i need to install to get json to work? i have the latest version of ruby and rails and am pretty sure json is automatically included.

Comment: No you don't have to install anything. Can you post the output of `alert(data, product)`? Put it in your success function of Ajax & make sure to put it after you initialized `product`

Comment: i added an alert and nothing shows up, so it seems like the success function isn't even running.

Comment: Have you replaced 'type: "JSON"' to 'dataType: "JSON"' ? see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: alright i finally got it to work. Instead of using $.ajax i used $.getJSON and followed the instructions on the link you provided. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome @notblakeshelton, "May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick." ;)

Comment: haha you as well. of course yoshi needs not be told to be quick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSON, return

```
{"item": "<%=j @product.item %>", "price": <%= @produce.price %>}
```

then `type: 'json'` in the ajax call

Comment: should I store that array in a variable and then just return it using <%= arrayvar %> or <% puts arrayvar %>? or do I need to use json.encode on it?

Comment: if you use `type: 'json'` jquery will parse it

Comment: shuckydarn i can't seem to get it to work. i have edited my question with the updated files if you'd like to take a look at it. i tried using your code but couldn't get it to work.